Shed plumbing connection to frost hydrant
I have an unclimatized detached shed with a frost hydrant so that it can be turned off for freezing temps. It is located in a corner of the shed. From that point, I would like to have PVC water supply plumbing to feed a hose bib on the outside of the shed and a utility sink in another corner of the shed. Before I ripped it out for redesign, I had it come off directly from the hydrant male end with an adapter. That was not ideal because detaching it required cutting PVC pipe, however cheap.
Is there a connector, like a hose, that can connect two firm ends of pipe yet is flexible for portability that would be suitable for this purpose? I would be happy if the plumbing sub-system started something like 1-2 ft away from the hydrant and that distanced bridged with something flexible or not even flexible but with unions on both ends so it can be taken out.

Sure, there are lots of flexible water piping materials.

PEX tubing: Even just a foot-long segment of PEX anchored at one end can be pushed/bent/displaced several inches at the other end.
Clothes washer hookup hose: female hose thread connectors at both ends
garden lead-in hose: a garden hose with female connector on one end and male on the other end, a few feet in length.

If you preferred the solid pipe and unions.. then why not go buy those parts and assemble it? Many of the white PVC parts sold in the irrigation aisle are marked NSF-pw, meaning they're approved for potable water use.
